What was the 80's/early 90's comedy where a couple moves into a bigger home and everyone's visiting them?
I'm looking for a movie starring Chevy Chase or Charles Grodin or someone looking alike.
A couple buys a new home, something big, and all relatives are moving in.
Or they may be a family, not a couple. I remember there was a teenage boy having pet snake. Snake ran away and tried to molest the wife while she was sleeping. She was like "Oh, %husbandname%, not now..." and then "Aaaah!". Next image is Chevy Chase and wife are looking down the toilet and flushing something, supposedly snake's remains.
Maybe there was a heavy metal (black clothes, heavy dark makeup) teenage girl. Hard to remember now, it's been about 25 years since I saw this movie.

Sounds like Madhouse from 1990 with Kirstie Alley and John Larroquette.  It doesn't have Chevy Chase or Charles Grodin.  John Larroquette could possibly be mistaken for either of those actors

@steelerfan this is most definitely the answer. I knew it was the answer but your comment beat me.

The movie that you are looking for sounds like Madhouse from 1990 starring Kirstie Alley and John Larroquette.  This movie does not star Chevy Chase or Charles Grodin; However, John Larroquette can easily be mistaken for either one of these actors.
Mark Bannister (Larroquette) and Jessie Bannister (Alley) live in a luxury villa.  They are overrun by cousins, sisters, nephews and neighbors.
There is not a snake, but a baby pet elephant with a "curious" trunk that seems to always have incontinent issues.
Also, there are always several people looking down the toilet because they are all told to jiggle the handle.

This begins when the mail of Mark and Jessie Bannister is delayed due
  to forwarding issues, and they find out a cousin, Fred, and his
  pregnant wife, Bernice, are flying in from New Jersey to visit. The
  Bannisters receive the letter on the day Fred and Bernice are expected
  to arrive. Though a little unpleasant, this only lasts five
  days...until Bernice falls on the way to the airport and is instructed
  by her doctor not to leave until she delivers six months later.


Ohh there is another Madhouse. I only remember one madhosue which people ask about again and again.

You are perfectly right, thank you. It was a great pleasure watching the movie again.

Hmm, sounds a lot like Funny Farm starring Chevy Chase. Here is the plot summary from IMDb:

When Andy and Elizabeth buy a farm in Vermont, they can't imagine the trouble that awaits them. Andy has quit his job as a sports journalist and is planning to use the peace and quiet of the country to write the Great American Novel. From the moment the movers' truck gets lost with their furniture, though, there's little peace and less quiet. From a manical mailman to a dead body buried in the garden, Andy is distracted by the town and its wacky inhabitants. His effort at a novel is mediocre, at best, and he's threatened by Elizabeth's foray into writing when she attempts a children's book. Can the Farmers survive the townsfolk and each other?


Funny Farm doesn't have relatives that move in with them.
